# This fizzbuzz code isn't working in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm pretty new to coding.  This fizzbuzz code isn't working any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using sublime text 3 and trying to produce results on vagrant using the node command. Thank You - Saad

```
for(i=101; i<201; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0){
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    };
    if(i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if(i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz")
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }``
}
```

Comment: The second `if` needs to be an `else if`. Also make sure `i` is declared with `let` or `var`.

Comment: "isn't working" http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: Given the nature of fizzbuzz, I'm concerned that this is an interview question.

Comment: Can you describe how its not working?  And what this code intends to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done like this:

```
for(i = 101; i < 201; i++) {
    var r = ""
    if (i % 3 === 0){
        r += "Fizz";
    }
    if(i % 5 === 0) {
        r += "Buzz";
    }
    if(i % (5 * 3) !== 0){ // or just 15
        r = i;
    }
    console.log(r);
}
```